# Using webpack in combination with Web Forms

Tags: c#, webpack, webforms

I have a webpack configuration that ties together all the dependencies for my web app.  The web app is pretty old and is made using Web Forms.  I'm going away from using the built in .NET minifier and bundle loader, and instead, towards using webpack's vendor packages etc.

My issue is that the web app is served out of a virtual directory, so I need to be able to reliably locate all required *.js files at runtime for the web app.  In my mind I reckon this looks like webpack "somehow" producing an output of what files it has written (including hashes etc), then somehow putting this into my master pages or something.  I know there is the HTML plugin for webpack but I don't know how to wrangle that to just produce a list of the *.js files, or if thats even on the right track.

How can I load my webpack'd *.js and *.css files from within Web Forms?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to install `assets-webpack-plugin` and configure it in your webpack. You can access this package here in [npmjs.org](https://www.npmjs.com/package/assets-webpack-plugin)

**Why Is This Useful?**

When working with Webpack you might want to generate your bundles with a generated hash in them (for cache busting). This plug-in outputs a `json` file with the paths of the generated assets so you can find them from somewhere else.

There is a good [tutorial](https://www.frederikvig.com/2009/08/adding-css-and-javascript-files-dynamically-to-your-asp-net-page/comment-page-1/) here to adding styles and scripts dynamically in ASPX.

```
{
    "one": {
        "js": "/js/one_2bb80372ebe8047a68d4.bundle.js"
    },
    "two": {
        "js": "/js/two_2bb80372ebe8047a68d4.bundle.js"
    }
}
```

In your `aspx` or master-page of your web-forms, you can easily deserilize this JSON and load your script and style assets in your page.

I'm using `assets-webpack-plugin` in my MVC project and I'm sure it wouldn't be a problem to use it in ASPX WebForms.